# Is it wrong that in a JWK, if the "d" value is **omitted**, that JWK represents a private key?

Tags: elliptic-curves, signature

This is not a programming question. This is to confirm whether a crypto documentation is incorrect.

I am using Rust's p384 crate. I am creating a private key from a JWK string.

In the source code, at line 85:

https://docs.rs/elliptic-curve/latest/src/elliptic_curve/jwk.rs.html#85

it says:

```
The `d` ECC private key parameter as described in RFC 7518 6.2.2.1:
<https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7518#section-6.2.2.1>
Value is optional and if omitted, this JWK represents a private key.
```

Isn't the last line wrong? It says "if omitted, this JWK represents a private key".

Shouldn't it say "if present, this JWK represents a private key"?

The RFC it links to:

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7518#section-6.2.2.1

says:

The "d" (ECC private key) parameter contains the Elliptic Curve private key value.

So, if this d value is omitted (as per the code comments), that wouldn't be a private key from what I understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm fairly confident that it's supposed to be "public key".

$d$ is the typical label for any "scalar" private key - decryption exponent in RSA or scalar factor in ECC. In RSA, public key is colloquially $(n,e)$, while in ECC, it's $Q$.

Comment: Thanks. I will file a bug report.